# How does a Fenestron remove or reduce the tip vortex losses in a helicopter?

Tags: fenestron

How are [Fenestrons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fenestron) (or fantails) able to reduce the tip vortex losses in a helicopter?

Comment: it's basically a ducted fan: http://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/13995

Comment: A link to some background information would be really helpful here: I have no idea who or what Fenestron is

Comment: Which tips, tail or main rotor?  If main rotor, they don't.  If tail rotor, the duplicate covers this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are basically two effects here:

- One is the ducted fan effect. Ducted fans are more efficient than open fans, specifically creating smaller vortices at the blade tips.
- The other is the fact that the tail rotor of a helicopter is **not** situated in an area with almost linear airflow along the rotor axis. It is also submitted to:

  - A steady flow due to helicopter forward motion. This is coming from the **side** of the rotor, so affects opposite rotor blades differently.
  - A buffeting flow from the h/c main rotor. This is an unsteady flow, also coming laterally from the point of view of the tail rotor (actually, the top).

Fenestron tail-rotor ducts can be considered a fairing that reduces airflow across the rotor. The end result is that the rotor blades are in a much smoother flow that helps reduce unwanted turbulence. This is one of the reasons such rotors are quieter than regular open tail-rotors (the other being the fairing material absorbing some of the noise).