# What's the efficiency between the duct and the fan blade?

Tags: aerodynamics, aircraft-physics, duct-fan

I've heard many times that the smaller the gap between the fan blade and the duct, the better the efficiency/thrust is.

Is there a formula or graph available to see how much efficiency is lost as you increase the distance from the fan blade to the duct?

[image: duct fan]

Comment: The answers [here](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/13995/70478) might help.

Comment: You may look at figure 10 - variations in efﬁciency and leakage with increased clearance, in [this document](https://www.euroturbo.eu/paper/ETC2017-250.pdf).

Answer (score 1):

Even for just a simple propulsive fan it'll be hard to find one formula incorporating the many practical input variables: blade radius, blade count, blade twist, rpm, airspeed, air density, rotor position in duct, duct narrowing, etc.  I find only measurements and simulations of particular families of these, e.g.

[Performance Investigation of Ducted Aerodynamic Propulsors, Bi et al, SMP 2009](https://www.marinepropulsors.com/proceedings/2009/TB2-2-Bi%20-%20Performance%20Investigation%20of%20Ducted%20Aerodynamic%20Propulsors.pdf),

whose conclusion, supported by measurements shown in Fig. 16 (for the same thrust, a gap of 1% to 3% wastes about 10% more power than zero gap), dares to claim nothing more rigorous than:

> Propulsor efficiency is insensitive to blade tip
> clearance when the tip gap is between 1%R and
> 3%R. However, as the tip clearance approaches
> zero, propulsor efficiency can be quite sensitive
> to gap size.